# How to reformat non-linear data to linear data?

Tags: python, format, record, nonlinear-functions

Let me elaborate:

I have a nonlinear time axis, say `[2.0,5.8,8.18,16.0,32.1]` (could be anything though)

I have a waveform recorded at the above times, say `[1,1,1,1,1,etc]`

I need to transfer waveform to linear `range(start,end,x)`, `[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,etc]`, where `x` is the number which allow me to keep all the data and not lose some along the way

So that it ends up as `[1,0,1,0,0,0,1,etc]`. No Interpolation

```
waveform [1,1,1,1,1,etc]
nonlin   [2.0,5.8,8.18,16.0,32.1]
lin  [0,0.01,0.02,0.03,etc]
new_wave = ...
```

My initial attempt would be to

(Sort of Pseudo):

```
make array of intervals between points # i.e. [3.8,2.38, etc]
find smallest interval
lin = np.arange(start,end,smallest_interval)
new_wave = np.zeros([ len(lin) ]) # empty array of same size as lin
for index, i in enumerate(lin):
    if i is in nonlin:
        find nonlin index, call it nonlin_index
        new_wave[index] = waveform[nonlin_index]
```

But this is going to take ages if I do it this way!

Is there a simpler technique?